# dbt invoke post-hook macro with list argument

Tags: jinja2, dbt

I'm trying to invoke a macro as a post-hook. The trouble is (I think) is that I'd like to pass a list to this macro... any idea what's going on here? My theory is that I'm passing a list type argument.

```sql
-- models/table.sql
{{
  config(
    materialized = 'table',
    post-hook = "{{ my_macro(this,'my_str', ['foo', 'bar']) }}"
    )
}}

SELECT * FROM muh_tayble;
```

```sql
-- macros/my_macro.sql
{% macro my_macro(relation, string, list) %}
 BLAH
{% endmacro %}
```

#### error message

```
Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in model table (models/table.sql)
  invalid syntax for function call expression
    line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rookie mistake folks. I had `post-hook` instead of `post_hook`. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

How to pass a variable to the macro set in the model?

Ex:
{% set run_id = call_audit(this, 'Running') %}

pass run_id variable to the macro success_audit (run_id) in post_hook

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).